# How to catch SIGTERM in a multi threaded Linux program using signalfd

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, c++17

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082302/signal-sigterm-handling-of-multi-thread-process-under-linux) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6949025/841108).

In the Linux GPLv3+ project https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/ (multi-threaded, C++17, web server application) commit [b616defc5e54ba869](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/b616defc5e54ba86980f4d90310c5e62f6b6188b). The need is to be able to terminate gracefully such a web server (interacting with some [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) database using `libpqxx`). So [issue#35](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/issues/35).

I did read both [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). And I am aware of [criticisms against signalfd](https://ldpreload.com/blog/signalfd-is-useless).

I have a single background C++ `std::thread`  [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)-ing on several file descriptors. See file [`hcv_background.cc`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_background.cc) where the `hcv_start_background_thread`  function is called from `main` function  in file [`hcv_main.cc`](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/blob/master/hcv_main.cc) and the created `std::thread` runs the `hcv_background_thread_body` function (an event loop doing the [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)....)

So `hcv_start_background_thread`  has:

```
  {
    sigset_t  sigmaskbits;
    memset (&sigmaskbits, 0, sizeof(sigmaskbits));
    sigemptyset(&sigmaskbits);
    sigaddset(&sigmaskbits, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&sigmaskbits, SIGHUP);
    sigaddset(&sigmaskbits, SIGXCPU);
    sigaddset(&sigmaskbits, SIGPIPE);
    /// http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigmaskbits, nullptr))
      HCV_FATALOUT("hcv_start_background_thread: sigprocmask failure");
    HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_start_background_thread sigprocmask done");
    hcv_bg_signal_fd = signalfd(-1, &sigmaskbits, SFD_NONBLOCK | SFD_CLOEXEC);
    if (hcv_bg_signal_fd < 0)
      HCV_FATALOUT("hcv_start_background_thread: signalfd failure");
    HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_start_background_thread hcv_bg_signal_fd=" << hcv_bg_signal_fd);
  }
```

and the `hcv_background_thread_body` function has an  event loop doing

```
  while (!hcv_should_stop_bg_thread.load())
    {
      struct pollfd polltab[4];
      memset(&polltab, 0, sizeof(polltab));
      polltab[0].fd = hcv_bg_event_fd;
      polltab[0].events = POLL_IN;
      polltab[1].fd = hcv_bg_signal_fd;
      polltab[1].events = POLL_IN;
      polltab[1].fd = hcv_bg_timer_fd;
      polltab[1].events = POLL_IN;
      HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body before poll");
      int nbfd = poll(polltab, 3,
                      hcv_debugging.load()?(2*HCV_BACKGROUND_TICK_TIMEOUT):HCV_BACKGROUND_TICK_TIMEOUT);
```

and later in the same event loop

```
 if (nbfd>0)   /* some file descriptor is readable */
        {
          HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body: after poll nbfd:" << nbfd);
          if ((polltab[0].revents & POLL_IN) && polltab[0].fd == hcv_bg_event_fd)
            {
              int64_t evrk=0;

              HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body pollable hcv_bg_event_fd="
                           << hcv_bg_event_fd);
              int byrd = read (hcv_bg_event_fd, &evrk, sizeof(evrk));
              if (byrd==sizeof(evrk))
                {
                  HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body: got " << evrk
                               << " from hcv_bg_event_fd=" << hcv_bg_event_fd);
                  hcv_bg_do_event(evrk);
                }
              else
                HCV_SYSLOGOUT(LOG_WARNING,
                              "hcv_background_thread_body read hcv_bg_event_fd#" <<hcv_bg_event_fd << " failed, byrd=" << byrd);
            };
          if ((polltab[1].revents & POLL_IN) && polltab[1].fd == hcv_bg_signal_fd)
            {
              HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body pollable hcv_bg_signal_fd="
                           << hcv_bg_signal_fd);
              struct signalfd_siginfo signalinfo;
              memset (&signalinfo, 0, sizeof(signalinfo));
              int byrd = read(hcv_bg_signal_fd, &signalinfo, sizeof(signalinfo));
              if (byrd < 0)
                HCV_FATALOUT("hcv_background_thread_body: failed read of hcv_bg_signal_fd="
                             << hcv_bg_signal_fd);
              else if (byrd != sizeof(signalinfo))
                // should never happen... see signalfd(2)
                HCV_FATALOUT("hcv_background_thread_body: corrupted read of hcv_bg_signal_fd="
                             << hcv_bg_signal_fd << ", byrd=" << byrd);
              HCV_DEBUGOUT("hcv_background_thread_body: got signalinfo #" << signalinfo.ssi_signo
                           << " from hcv_bg_signal_fd=" << hcv_bg_signal_fd);
              if (signalinfo.ssi_signo == SIGTERM)
                {
                  HCV_SYSLOGOUT(LOG_NOTICE, "hcv_background_thread_body got SIGTERM at "
                                << (hcv_monotonic_real_time() - hcv_monotonic_start_time)
                                << " elapsed seconds");
                  hcv_process_SIGTERM_signal();
                  hcv_should_stop_bg_thread.store (true);
                }
```

But `hcv_process_SIGTERM_signal`  never got called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - writing a web app framework in C++? It might be an interesting intellectual exercise, but if your goal is to deliver something useful then there's value to *delivering something* so you can learn and iterate on it. Its great to choose a license and all, but it can handle zero requests per second until users can deploy (and think "Deploy to Heroku" button rather than Linux sysadmin) and try it!

Comment: Well, other partners don't know [ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/) and I don't know and don't want to learn PHP or Python. There are several people suggesting writing a web application in C++.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2055175/841108

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible, or that people don't want to do it (...ten years ago), just that if what you want to do is actually help people then *software in production* is better than an endless research project.

Comment: It is neither in production nor a research project.

Comment: It's OK, there's nothing wrong with learning for its own sake, but be realistic about the value you're delivering. If you want to have an impact you may want to expand your network to people who can actually ship software products to end users, not just modern dev skills but design and product too.

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I don't have any MCVE (and I don't have neither the time nor the motivation to make one). I do have however a reproducible test case. I am considering using techniques inspired by [calling Qt functions from unix signal handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Your code have errors elsewhere, `singnalfd` and `poll` work as expected.

Comment: Yes, thanks.... Any debugging hints to debug a multi-threaded program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
if (sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sigmaskbits, nullptr))
```

Should be:

```
if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigmaskbits, nullptr))
```

[`man signalfd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html):

> Normally, the set of signals to be received via the
>          file descriptor should be **blocked** using `sigprocmask(2)`, to prevent
>          the signals being handled according to their default dispositions.
>
> Program source

```
...
/* Block signals so that they aren't handled
   according to their default dispositions */
   if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL) == -1)
       handle_error("sigprocmask");
...
```

---

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void another_thread(int sfd) {
    pollfd fds[2];
    fds[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;
    fds[1].fd = sfd;
    fds[1].events = POLLIN;

    for(;;) {
        int n = poll(fds, 2, -1);
        if(n <= 0)
            throw;
        if(fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            char buf[1024];
            ssize_t r = read(fds[0].fd, buf, sizeof buf);
            if(r > 0)
                std::cout << "Read " << r << " bytes\n";
            else if(!r) {
                std::cout << "Read EOF\n";
                break;
            }
            else
                throw;
        }
        if(fds[1].revents & POLLIN) {
            signalfd_siginfo s;
            ssize_t r = read(fds[1].fd, &s, sizeof s);
            if(r != sizeof s)
                throw;
            std::cout << "Received signal " << s.ssi_signo << '\n';
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
    if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, nullptr) == -1)
        throw;

    int sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0);
    if(sfd == -1)
        throw;

    std::thread(another_thread, sfd).join();

    std::cout << "Terminated successfully\n";
}
```

Output:

```
[max@supernova:~/src/test] $ ./test 
  C-c C-cReceived signal 2
Terminated successfully
```

---

Another error in your code is:

```
      polltab[0].events = POLL_IN;
      polltab[1].fd = hcv_bg_signal_fd;
      polltab[1].events = POLL_IN;
      polltab[1].fd = hcv_bg_timer_fd;
      polltab[1].events = POLL_IN;
```

`hcv_bg_timer_fd` should probably use index 2.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this in commit [2ae9549245a](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/commit/2ae9549245a5ac6705570c78fcbb5cdedfaee307) but it still does not work

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Added a working example for you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch My code does use `std::thread`. Your code must have errors elsewhere.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Found another error in your code, updated.

Comment: Thanks a big lot for your help